# How to work with dynamics 365 in .net 6/7?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I was going through related posts all around internet but didn't find anything helpful which compatible .net 6/7. Found out Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client package but not sure about this. Can somebody suggest me the proper way/packages to modernize our .net framework solution to work with dynamics 365?

Comment: I would recommend to look at use the Dynamics REST API instead of the Dataverse client - seems to work just fine, often a lot quicker, and is independent of any .NET runtime version etc. - just simple HTTP requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet package `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client` is the first choice when connecting to Dataverse/Dynamics 365 CE from external .NET components. It targets the .NET Frameworks 4.6.2, 4.7.2, 4.8, .NET Core and .NET 6.0.

There is still some tooling from MS targeting other frameworks that occasionally can force you to work with that, but when possible I would choose package `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client`.

Edit: for on premises deployments keep using older technology.

Comment: I couldn't find proper documentation about this package and its usage. Maybe you have some some resources? :D

Comment: @ShahinJabbarov https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/sdk-client-transition